# Express Compress not working in Node website

Tags: node.js, express, gzip

I've my site built on node + express, and trying to enable gzip compression using [this](https://medium.com/@victor.valencia.rico/gzip-compression-with-node-js-cc3ed74196f9#:%7E:text=To%20start%20using%20compression%20in,which%20supports%20different%20compression%20schemes.) tutorial but it didn't worked as shown in the tutorial. I can't see Content-Encoding in response header.

Here is my code.

```
const compression = require('compression');
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var redirects = require('express-seo-redirects');
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
require('dotenv').config()
/**
 * App Variables
*/
const app = express();
app.use(compression({ filter: shouldCompress, threshold: 0 }));
//app.use(compression()) - //I've also tried this.
function shouldCompress (req, res) {
  if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) {
    // don't compress responses with this request header
   return false
  }

  // fallback to standard filter function
  return compression.filter(req, res)
}
let setCache = function (req, res, next) {
  // here you can define period in second, this one is 1 day
  const period = 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 

  // you only want to cache for GET requests
  if (req.method == 'GET') {
    res.set('Cache-control', `public, max-age=${period}`)
  } else {
    // for the other requests set strict no caching parameters
    res.set('Cache-control', `no-store`)
  }
  // res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
  // remember to call next() to pass on the request
  next()
}
app.use(setCache)
```

And when I use `res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')` inside `app.get("/", (req, res) => {` then it shows in response header but website stop working (not showing any error other than blank screen).

Bellow images are of my rest code.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gzip compression was showing only for resource files (css, js etc..). So I resolved it by adding `res.contentType('text/html');` in setCache function.

```
const exceptions = ['.js', '.css', '.ico', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.tiff', '.tif', '.bmp', '.svg', '.ttf', '.eot', '.woff', '.php', '.xml', '.xsl'];
let setCache = function (req, res, next) {
  // here you can define period in second, this one is 5 minutes
  const period = 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  if(!exceptions.some(v => req.url.includes(v))){
    res.contentType('text/html');
  }
  // you only want to cache for GET requests
  if (req.method == 'GET') {
    res.set('Cache-control', `public, max-age=${period}`)
  } else {
    // for the other requests set strict no caching parameters
    res.set('Cache-control', `no-store`)
  }
  // res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
  // remember to call next() to pass on the request
  next()
}
app.use(setCache)
```